# Google Cloud App Engine - Deploy multiple environments

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

For my application, I have two different environments on GCP: staging and production. My static Angular application is currently deployed on GAE. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to deploy these two environments separately with two different URL's? Or is there another solution better suited for such a setup?

If not I'll probably have to switch back to Google Cloud Run.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 environments = 2 projects! It's easier and you have App Engine free tier duplicated (per projet)

If you deploy 2 time the same package on the same GAE (so, on the same project), you need to have a app.yaml per deployment. And thus your staging deployment pipeline isn't exactly the same as the production deployment pipeline. And the URL format also. The non default service has his URL prefixed with the service name. And you should have issues with handlers definitions, the scheduler (if you have one),....

No, the easiest is to have 1 project per environment

Comment: Another option is to use a different service for staging.  In some situations, you'll want to test with production data before going live though of course you need to be careful to mess up your production data.